Angular 16 SSR и реплики в Docker Compose
Помогите разобраться с вопросом. Запускаю приложение Angular 16 с SSR и гидратацией используя Docker Compose с приведенным примером и всё работает нормально. Но хочу запустить несколько реплик для front используя комманду docker-compose up --scale front=3 -d - контейнеры запускаются, но в логах каждой реплики всегда одна и таже ошибка  Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '_rawValidators'), что приводит к неработоспособности приложения. Может быть проблема с гидратацией, но это не точно.
version: '3.7'

services:
    traefik:
        image: traefik:v2.4
        command:
            - "--providers.docker=true"
            - "--entrypoints.web.address=:80"
            - "--entrypoints.websecure.address=:443"
            - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.tlschallenge=true"
            - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.email=${EMAIL}"
            - "--certificatesresolvers.myresolver.acme.storage=/letsencrypt/acme.json"
        ports:
            - "80:80"
            - "443:443"
        volumes:
            - "/var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock"
            - "./letsencrypt:/letsencrypt"
        labels:
            - "traefik.http.middlewares.traefik-compress.compress=true"
        networks:
            - internal
        restart: always

    front:
        build:
            context: .
            dockerfile: Dockerfile
        labels:
            - "traefik.enable=true"
            - "traefik.http.routers.front.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN_NAME}`) || Host(`${DOMAIN_WWW_NAME}`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.front.entrypoints=web"
            - "traefik.http.routers.front.middlewares=redirect-to-https@docker,redirect-to-non-www@docker,traefik-compress"
            - "traefik.http.routers.front-secure.rule=Host(`${DOMAIN_NAME}`) || Host(`${DOMAIN_WWW_NAME}`)"
            - "traefik.http.routers.front-secure.entrypoints=websecure"
            - "traefik.http.routers.front-secure.tls=true"
            - "traefik.http.routers.front-secure.tls.certresolver=myresolver"
            - "traefik.http.routers.front-secure.middlewares=redirect-to-non-www@docker,traefik-compress"
            - "traefik.http.services.front.loadbalancer.server.port=4000"
            - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.scheme=https"
            - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-https.redirectscheme.permanent=true"
            - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-non-www.redirectregex.regex=^https?://${DOMAIN_WWW_NAME}/(.*)"
            - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-non-www.redirectregex.replacement=https://${DOMAIN_NAME}/$${1}"
            - "traefik.http.middlewares.redirect-to-non-www.redirectregex.permanent=true"
        networks:
            - internal
        restart: always

networks:
    internal:
        driver: bridge

Dockerfile:
FROM node:22.8-alpine
WORKDIR /app
COPY ./package.json ./package-lock.json /app/
RUN npm install
COPY . /app
EXPOSE 4000
RUN npm run build:ssr
CMD npm run serve:ssr

